# Why both arm and thumb compiling in Eclipse ADT?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, arm, thumb

I am using the ndk along with Eclipse ADT to build apps for Android and it works fine. However I am wondering why the building process involves compiling both for arm and for thumb, ie every time I do a modification in a source file it re-compiles both for arm and thumb. Is it necessary ? If not how can I tell the builder to only compile and link with armabi-V7a ? That would divide by 2 my build process time...

Comment: Currently, android libraries tend to use a mix of ARM and THUMB instructions - internal functionality is typically THUMB while external linkage hooks are ARM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably mean, for arm v6 and arm v7a? Both can be compiled as ARM or THUMB. This is controlled by LOCAL_ARM_MODE in **Android.mk**. To disable **armeabi**, set

```
APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a
```

in **Application.mk**. This will not only reduce your build time, but also the size of your APK.

Comment: I found the answer. I use Juce framework and it automatically generates the Android.mk file with a test like this in it:
ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI), armeabi-v7a)
    LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm
endif
There is a default setting in Juce where it asks for both armeabi and armeabi-V7a libraries. I changed that to just armeabi-V7a and don't get the double build process (arm+thumb) anymore.
But your answer helped me looking at the right place, hence the +1...
:)

Comment: I cannot tell why they don't like thumb code on arm v7a, but even if you delete the **ifeq**, you still have double build, which is a nuisance if you only target modern devices.